# UITableViewCell subclass: Delete and reorder button not showing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, subclassing

I am using a UITableViewCell subclass in a highly customized UITableView. Now I want to implement a edit button. So I implemented a button, an action, setting the UITableview to editing:YES and so on. The problem is that my cells do not show the delete or move buttons or handlers. Do I need to implement something in my subclass for this?

Bests,
Philip

Answer (score -1):

do like this complete implementation of edit and delete buttons in tableview, customize according to your requirement

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Referrral RemainderCC";

    referrralRemainderCC *cell = (referrralRemainderCC *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"referrralRemainderCC" bundle:nil];
        cell = (referrralRemainderCC *) c.view;

    }
    if (dataArray.count==0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        referralDC *referral =[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lblDate.text = referral.referralDC_Date;
        cell.lblCompanyName.text = referral.referralDC_CompanyName;
        cell.lblEmail.text = referral.referralDC_EmailTelephone;
        cell.lblFellowUpDate.text = referral.referralDC_FellowUpDate;
        cell.lblReferralRequest.text =referral.referralDC_ReferralRequest;
        cell.lblName.text = referral.referralDC_Name;
        cell.edit.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell.delete.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.edit addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.delete addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:withEvents:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];       
    }
    return cell;

}
- (void)btnTapped:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.tblView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];


   referralDC *referral =[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    referalID = referral.referralDC_ReferralID;
    txtDate.text = referral.referralDC_Date; 
    txtCompanyName.text = referral.referralDC_CompanyName;
    txtEmail.text = referral.referralDC_EmailTelephone;
    txtFolowUpDate.text = referral.referralDC_FellowUpDate;
    txtviewReferralRequest.text =referral.referralDC_ReferralRequest;
    txtName.text = referral.referralDC_Name;

    btnEditPressed=1;

}
```